# awk search a line withing a file

Tags: awk

I am trying to find occurrences of a STRING in some other file:

First I extract the STRING exactly I want to search:

```
grep STRING test.txt | cut -d"," -f3 | tr -d ' '
```

Now I proceed to search it in other file - so my command is:

```
grep STRING test.txt | cut -d"," -f3 | tr -d ' ' | awk '/$0/' temp.txt
```

I am getting 0 rows output - but comparing manually I do find the strings common in both files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pipe like that. You'd need to use a sub-shell; something like:

```
grep $(grep STRING test.txt | cut -d"," -f3 | tr -d ' ') temp.txt
```

Alternatively, use `awk` like this:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR && /STRING/ { gsub(/ /,""); a[$3]; next } FNR!=NR { for (i in a) if ($0 ~ i) { print; next } }' test.txt temp.txt
```

Comment: awk -F, 'FNR==NR {if($0~/STRING/){gsub(/ /,"");a[$3];next }}{for(i in a)if($0~/i/){print;}}' test.txt temp.txt

Comment: Just be aware that in neither the awk case nor the grep case are you actually searching for a STRING - all of the matches above use regular-expression comparisons, not string comparisons so if "STRING" contains an RE-metacharacter like ., *, ? etc. then you will get matches you may not want. If that's unacceptable let us know and we can show you how to do string comparisons instead of RE comparisons.